# Undefined variable array on JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome, undefined

wondering if someone could help with this.

I have this script that refuses to work on newest version of my browsers (works in older versions) and would like some help on solving the issue/s.

You have to install it on your chrome browser, by saving the code below as a file with the filename: "test.user.js"
Then drag the file into the extensions tab of your browser (>settings>extensions on chrome) and activate it.
Then open [madbid.com](http://madbid.com) on the browser, click on an active auction, inspect the element where the name of the bidder appear everytime someone bid and copy that id into the text field above "GO MONITOR" (it looks something like `mbal1_ac2560454_bidder`). Then click "GO MONITOR" and the chart starts.

The main issue i have is: under the "GO MONITOR" button it shows `undefined` instead of recording the names of the players as they bid with the relative bids counts.

The second one, Chrome do not display the graph at all, instead it render a solid grey background. On Firefox the graph does work, but no players name list still.

Here's the code:

```
(function(){
    var madbidMonitor = {};
    madbidMonitor = function() {
        this.layerMonitor = null;
        this.players = Array();
        this.totalPujas = 0;
        this.lastPlayerName = "";
        this.oContent = null;
        this.timer=0;
        this._init();
        this.chart = null;
        return this;
    };
    madbidMonitor.prototype = {
        _init:function() {
            var _this = this;
            var w = window,
                d = document,
                e = d.documentElement,
                g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
                x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
                y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
            var layer = document.createElement("div"); 
            layer.style.position = 'absolute';
            layer.style.top = "0px";
            layer.style.right = "0px";
            layer.style.background = "#555";
            layer.style.border = "1px solid #fff";
            layer.style.color = "#fff";
            layer.style.width = "140px";
            layer.style.height = y+"px";
            layer.style.overflow ='scroll';
            layer.style.fontSize = '10px';
            document.body.appendChild(layer);
            this.oContent = layer;
            //
            var o = document.createElement("div");
            o.id = 'madbidmonchart';
            o.style.position = 'fixed';
            o.style.bottom = "20px";
            o.style.left = "0px";
            o.style.background = "#555";
            o.style.border = "1px solid #333";
            o.style.color = "#fff";
            o.style.width = (x-160)+"px";
            o.style.height = (y-600)+"px";
            document.body.appendChild(o);
            //
            var idDivText = this._getRandomID();
            var idDivBtn = this._getRandomID();
            layer.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="'+idDivText+'"/>';
            layer.innerHTML += '<input id="'+idDivBtn+'" type="button" value="GO MONITOR"/>';
            //
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.onload = function(){_this.Charts()};
            script.src = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            //
            document.getElementById(idDivBtn).addEventListener('click', function(){
                _this.layerMonitor = document.getElementById(document.getElementById(idDivText).value);
                setInterval(function(){_this.IntervalMonitor.call(_this)},100);
            });

        }
        ,
        _getRandomID : function(){
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*100000000)+1);
        }
        ,
        findPlayer : function(name) {
            for(var n=0; n<this.players.length; n++) {
                if(this.players[n].name==name) return n;
            }
            return false;
        }
        ,
        IntervalMonitor : function() {
            this.timer += 0.1;
            if(!this.layerMonitor) return;
            this.oContent.style.top = window.pageYOffset+"px";

            if(this.layerMonitor.style.display=='none'){
                this.lastPlayerName='';
                return;
            }

            var actualPlayerName = this.layerMonitor.innerText;
            var actualPlayer = this.findPlayer(actualPlayerName);
            if(actualPlayer===false) {
                this.players.push({name:actualPlayerName, pujas:1, history: [this.timer]});
                this.chart.addSeries({name:actualPlayerName, data:[[this.timer,1]]});
                this.lastPlayerName=actualPlayerName;
                this.totalPujas++;
            }
            else {
                if(this.lastPlayerName!=actualPlayerName){
                    this.players[actualPlayer].pujas++;
                    this.players[actualPlayer].history.push(this.timer);
                    this.chart.series[actualPlayer].addPoint([this.timer, this.players[actualPlayer].pujas]);
                    this.lastPlayerName=actualPlayerName;
                    this.totalPujas++;
                }
            }

            this.Paint();
        }
        ,
        Paint : function() {
            this.oContent.innerHTML = "<b>Total pujas:</b> " + this.totalPujas+"<br>";
            for(var n=0; n<this.players.length; n++){
                this.oContent.innerHTML += "<b>"+this.players[n].name+":</b> "+this.players[n].pujas+"<br>";
            }
        }
        ,
        Charts : function() {
            this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'madbidmonchart',
                type: 'line',
                animation: false,
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'MADBID APUESTAS MONITOR'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'by <a href="http://www.polimalo.com/" target="_blank">PoliMalo.com</a> / <a href="http://polilabs.com/" target="_blank">PoliLabs.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'linear'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Apuestas'
                },
                min: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ (this.x/60.0).toFixed(2) +' min<br> '+ this.y+" apuestas";
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            series: []
        });
        }
    }

    new madbidMonitor();

})();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any ideas at all where the problem could be? What changes that you made didn't work?

Comment: I have tried only minor changes, like changing Array() with [] but I believe there is more to it. I just am not familiar with java language, I work mostly with html & css. Not really helpful i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's this script error (even without your script loaded):

```
initImageSettings(): $( ".auction_thumbnail" ).eq( 1 ).attr( "id" ) is undefined.
```

That very likely causes further problems along the way, so you need to fix that first.

Then: your graph is not being displayed because Chrome deems the scripts from highcharts.com as unsafe:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com".
```

You also have a problem with mixed `http` and `https` connections:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/hub.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

My suggestion: find someone who can help you with these Javascript problems. If you don't know what you're doing this will drive you nuts.

#### Edit

Someone seems to be working on the page actively. The first error I described above is now gone.

Comment: You are a superstar! Your help was enough to figure it out :) The error was that unsafe call to the script, so I redirected all the scripts calls internally to my 127.0.0.1 server, copied the files and now is working! Thanks a bunch :) Question: what debug program did you use to get those comments? ("refused" etc)

Comment: Glad that helped. Chrome developer tools (on Mac: View -> developer -> developer tools). Would have looked the same in Safari or Firefox dev tools.